# Show Core Data date in DetailTextlabel

Tags: ios, date

Hi so i wanna show a Date from  CoreData which is called "expireDate"+ a text in the detailTextLabel of my TableView.
The Text i wanne show is always the same, so its not in the CoreData

The current method to implement the whole thing is like this:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Inventory *inventory = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = inv.invProName;
    cell.detailTextLabel. //<---- Here i should set the Date, but how?
}
```

The `cell.textLabel.text`works perfectly

can someone help me?

Comment: so is the date in your core data database a `NSDate` object?

Comment: yes, it is a NSDate object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it sounds like you need to get accustomed to using a date formatter.

What you probably want to do is something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSDate *dt = inv.invDate;
NSString *dateAsString = [formatter stringFromDate:dt];
[formatter release];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Expire Date %@", dateAsString];
```

And there are *lots* of NSDateFormatter questions found here on Stackoverflow, and [here's a tutorial you can look at](http://gtiapps.com/?p=1086), to help get accustomed to it.